# Background transfer of HLS using makeAssetDownloadTask only downloads about half of the data

Tags: ios, swift, http-live-streaming

I am using `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`'s `makeAssetDownloadTask` method on iOS 15 and iOS 16 to simultaneously play and download an HLS VOD stream. Sample code:

```
@objc func createDownloadSession() {
    // Create new background session configuration.
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "TestAppSession")
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60 * 60 * 2
    
    // Create a new AVAssetDownloadURLSession with background configuration, delegate, and queue
    downloadSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: configuration,
                                                assetDownloadDelegate: self,
                                                delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
}

@objc func downloadAndCreatePlayerItem(_ url: URL) -> AVPlayerItem? {
    // Create new AVAssetDownloadTask for the desired asset
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

    // Create the task to download the track.
    let downloadTask = downloadSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset,
                                                         assetTitle: "Test Title",
                                                         assetArtworkData: nil,
                                                         options: nil)

    // Start task
    downloadTask!.resume()

    // Return the URL asset
    return AVPlayerItem(asset: downloadTask!.urlAsset)
}
```

Everything seems to work fine; it starts pulling the data down at a fast rate, and plays the audio immediately.

However, after a few seconds it stops downloading. It seems to only load around 15 minutes of the HLS audio (I can see the `loadedTimeRanges`).

How do I get it to download the entire HLS stream? Is there some throttling I am encountering by the OS? The app is in the foreground, though it is a background session. Anything I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this problem? ;)

Comment: Nope! Even used one of my Apple Code-Level Support credits and they have no idea why it's occurring. It's pretty clear that when using this API it doesn't actually download anything in the background, and instead just streams the HLS audio directly. The `loadedTimeRanges` look the same if I remove all of the download logic; behavior is the same. I also get no delegate callbacks for the download. I moved to a solution where I just download up front and then play the downloaded file, but would really prefer if the API worked as designed.